# simple_xml_string not working when using $_POST

Tags: php, simplexml

I need some help figuring out why I can't use $_POST['status'] with simplexml_load_string.

I am posting some data to a php page, then reading in $_POST['status'].  The xml located inside $_POST['status'] then needs to be read into php's simplexml_load_string so I can parse the xml into an object.

If I hard code the simplexml_load_string() like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?>
                                <BackgroundReports userId="" password="" databaseset="">
                                  <BackgroundReportPackage>
                                    <ReferenceId>1|9</ReferenceId>
                                    <OrderId>107284</OrderId>
                                    <ScreeningStatus>
                                      <OrderStatus flag="FALSE">x:partial</OrderStatus>
                                    </ScreeningStatus>
                                    <Screenings>
                                      <Screening type="credit">
                                        <ScreeningResults type="result" mediaType="html" resultType="report">
                                          <InternetWebAddress><![CDATA[https://somewhere.com]]></InternetWebAddress> 
                                        </ScreeningResults>
                                      </Screening>
                                    </Screenings>
                                  </BackgroundReportPackage>
                                </BackgroundReports>');
```

And dump it with var_dump($xml)  The output is:

```
XML

object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["databaseset"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["BackgroundReportPackage"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (4) {
    ["ReferenceId"]=>
    string(3) "1|9"
    ["OrderId"]=>
    string(6) "107284"
    ["ScreeningStatus"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
      ["OrderStatus"]=>
      string(9) "x:partial"
    }
    ["Screenings"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
      ["Screening"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["type"]=>
          string(6) "credit"
        }
        ["ScreeningResults"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (2) {
          ["@attributes"]=>
          array(3) {
            ["type"]=>
            string(6) "result"
            ["mediaType"]=>
            string(4) "html"
            ["resultType"]=>
            string(6) "report"
          }
          ["InternetWebAddress"]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (0) {
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However if I use the $_POST['status'] like this `$xml = simplexml_load_string($_POST['status']);` instead of hard coding, then simplexml_load_string does not work.   I know that $_POST['status'] has all the same xml...I dumped it out and it is exactly the same as when I hardcode it as a parameter to simple_xml_string.

the output now becomes this when I try to use $_POST['status']:

```
XML

bool(false)
```

I need to figure out how to be able to use this with $_POST['status'] as the affiliate will only POST back to my php page.

Comment: Simple answer: the `$_POST['status']` is NOT the same. Find out why, that's the harder part, can't do that from here, try to `var_dump` instead of echo it.

Comment: I var_dumped...I've compared the output from var_dump and cut 'n pasted it directly into the code so it was hard coded...and it works...but the problem is I can't hard code it...I need it from the post variable...and that still does not work.

Comment: Did you copy/paste from the _source_ of the page or just the output in your browser?

Comment: Are you doing the `var_dump` on a web page? Then do `var_dump(htmlentities($_POST['status']));`, otherwise the browser will interpret the XML as HTML.

Comment: http://php.net/simplexml_load_string - read about the return value of that function. FALSE means the string you load is not valid XML. That simple it is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have magic quotes enabled on your host. You can make a simple test form and POST to see.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        echo 'Magic quotes enabled, so GET,POST,REQUEST,COOKIE Strings are escaped';
        $status = stripslashes($_POST['status']);
    }else{
        $status = $_POST['status'];
    }

    print_r(simplexml_load_string($status));
}else{
?>
<h1>Test XML POST</h1>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <p><textarea rows="9" name="status" cols="36"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Also adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` wont hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped me out.  Here is what I found out.  When I was "Posting" there was an extra line in the xml like this

```
"

<?xml version="1.0"?>bla bla
"
```

When I removed the blank line like this it all worked.

```
"<?xml version="1.0"?>bla bla
"
```